# Why Nothing == (pure Nothing) returns False in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Seems I understood something wrong, but I tried the following:

```
GHCi, version 8.6.5
Nothing == Nothing
=> True
Nothing == (pure Nothing)
=> False
pure Nothing
=> Nothing
```

Could you please explain what happens here?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be equal? What type do you think `pure Nothing` has?

Comment: I was lost because of prompt output

Comment: Sorry, I'd somehow missed the final output - that is indeed confusing (and not what I would have expected).

Comment: for the applicative `f ~ Maybe`, `pure = Just`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two `pure Nothing` in your code use a different `pure`.

If you examine the type of `pure Nothing`, you can see that the version of `pure` that is chosen depends on a type `f`.

```
GHCi> :t pure Nothing
pure Nothing :: Applicative f => f (Maybe a)
```

When you enter `pure Nothing` in interactive mode, `f` is inferred as `IO` and the result of the `IO` operation is printed. This is shortcut provided by GHCi that does not happen in regular Haskell code.

```
GHCi> pure Nothing
Nothing
GHCi> pure Nothing :: IO (Maybe ())
Nothing
```

However, when comparing `pure Nothing` with `Nothing`, `f` is inferred as `Maybe`. This creates two layers of `Maybe`, making the type `Maybe (Maybe a)`

```
GHCi> Nothing == pure Nothing
False
GHCi> Just Nothing == pure Nothing
True
GHCi> pure Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe ())
Just Nothing
```

Comment: To add: with `TypeApplications`, we can explicitly write out the type arguments with the defaults provided by ghci via `ExtendedDefaultRules`—`Nothing @()` has type `Maybe ()`, `pure @Maybe @(Maybe ()) (Nothing @())` has type `Maybe (Maybe ())`, and `pure @IO @(Maybe ()) (Nothing @())` has type `IO (Maybe ())`.